# Cocoa: Accessibility (VoiceOver) for buttons with image only

Tags: macos, cocoa, accessibility, voiceover

I use NSButton with empty title and image on it, and it cannot be accessed with VoiceOver. 
But when I'm setting title (VoiceOver seems to use title), NSButton tries to show it.

I think there should be an easy way to not display title, or to set button text, used by VoiceOver, however quick search didn't give any results yet.

P.S. I'm creating button programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved issue - added subclass for NSButtonCell, which does nothing in drawTitle: method and returns NSZeroRect. Seems to work ok.

Answer (score 4):

you must assign the accessibilityLabel to the image object directly, It works this way.